# Knockout css binding with duplicate classes

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I've just got cracking with Knockout.js and have run into my first stumbling block, though I'm not sure whether this is a bug or whether I'm not doing something properly.

When using the **css** binding, on the first condition when applying multiple classes, if more than one class name contains a "-" only one is applied. This does not occur with subsequent conditions and if I remove the "-" from the class name, the class is successfully applied.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pU9UR/

So this doesn't work:

```
 <i class="fa"  data-bind="    css: {  'fa-caret-down text-info': active() && !asc(), 'fa-caret-up text-info': active() && asc(), 'fa-unsorted text-muted': !active() }">
```

Whereas this does:

```
<i class="fa"  data-bind="    css: {  'fa-caret-down textinfo': active() && !asc(),'fa-caret-up text-info': active() && asc(), 'fa-unsorted text-muted': !active() }"></i>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

It appears my original diagnosis was wrong, the issue occurs when I have the same class repeated for different conditions. So the below does not work (only `fa-caret-down` is applied):

```
css: {  'fa-caret-down text-danger': active() && !asc(), 'fa-caret-up text-danger': active() && asc(), 'fa-unsorted text-muted': !active() }
```

But this does:

```
css: {  'fa-caret-down text-danger': active() && !asc(), 'fa-caret-up text-info': active() && asc(), 'fa-unsorted text-muted': !active() }
```

New fiddle that's easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/pU9UR/1/

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your fiddle is working fine for me in Chrome32... http://jsfiddle.net/73Kh3/ changed text-info to text-dandger for the better visibility

Comment: Chrome32, that's odd, text-danger works fine for me, but text-info on my fiddle the down caret is black - ah actually no, I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is not a bug but the feature of how the [`css` binding works](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

> The css binding **adds or removes one or more named CSS** classes to the associated DOM element.

So when KO goes through all of the properties of the `css` bound object it does the following:

- takes the `'fa-caret-down text-danger'` property and checks the expression `active() && !asc()` if it evaluates to **true** then it **adds the new classes** `fa-caret-down` and `text-danger`
- takes the `'fa-caret-up text-danger'` property and checks the expression `active() && asc()` which is the opposite of the previous so it is **false** and now it **removes the existing classes**: it could not find `fa-caret-up` but the `text-danger` is exists so it removes it.

So to make it work you need to move out the common part to use a different condition:

```
<i class="fa" data-bind="css: { 
    'fa-caret-down': active() && !asc(), 
    'fa-caret-up': active() && asc(), 
    'fa-unsorted text-muted': !active(), 
    'text-danger': active  }"></i>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJL5f/).

Comment: Thanks, got it now, made my brain hurt a little bit though ;)